# XAML DataTemplate with parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, .net-core, uwp-xaml

I have a data template that is:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CalDescButton">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Style="{StaticResource LargeIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xEC92;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Foreground="Transparent"
                    Style="{StaticResource MediumIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xEC92;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Foreground="Transparent"
                    Style="{StaticResource MediumIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xEC92;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Foreground="Transparent"
                    Style="{StaticResource MediumIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xEC92;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Foreground="Transparent"
                    Style="{StaticResource MediumIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xEC92;" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="0,-6,0,0"
                    Foreground="Aqua"
                    Style="{StaticResource XSmallIconStyle}"
                    Text="&#xF0AD;" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Then I have other 6 where the only thing that changes is the Text Char code.
Those templates are applied to buttons:

```
               <ToggleButton
                    Command="{Binding CmdSetSorting, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="CalAsc"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CalDescButton}" />
```

The question is: can I pass a variable to the template and use it in the Text="" instead of having 6 different templates just for that?
How can I do it?

Just to be clear I'd like to have something like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IconButton">
```

and then:

```
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconButton (&#xF0AD;)}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set Content property of Button:

```
<ToggleButton
    Command="{Binding CmdSetSorting, Mode=OneWay}"
    CommandParameter="CalAsc"
    Content="&#xEC92;"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CalDescButton}" />
```

it should become DataContext of root element in DataTemplate (because it is ContentTemplate) and will be accessible by Binding:

```
<TextBlock
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Style="{StaticResource LargeIconStyle}"
    Text="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Worked for one :) If I have to pass 2? any suggestion?

Comment: @MassimoSavazzi, I would say it would be better to create a `CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton` button control, add necessary dependency propeties, and transform ContentTemplate into ControlTemplate